# get data from $http response using angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, json

I have server written in Java, where I create JSON objects like this:

```
@Override
public void serialize(Net net, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    try {
        Set<Place> places = net.getPlaces();
        Set<Transition> transitions = net.getTransitions();
        JSONObject jsonPlaces = new JSONObject();
        for (Place p : places)
        {
            String id = p.getId();
            double xCoord = p.getxCoord();
            double yCoord = p.getyCoord();
            JSONObject jsonPosition = new JSONObject();
            jsonPosition.put("x", xCoord);
            jsonPosition.put("y", yCoord);

            JSONObject jsonPlace = new JSONObject();
            jsonPlace.put("position", jsonPosition);
            jsonPlaces.put(id, jsonPlace);
        }
        jg.writeRawValue(jsonPlaces.toString());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IOException("...", ex);
    } 
}
```

The resulting object as string (`jsonPlaces.toString()`) looks like this:

```
{"id01":{"position":{"x":220,"y":90}},"id02":{"position":{"x":210,"y":250}}}
```

I send it to my web application using the code below, it uses the `serialize()` method..

```
@POST
@Path("/blindLayout")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Net blindLayout(Net net) throws Exception {
    .
    .
    return net;
}
```

And here is the angularjs code that should recieve the response

```
.factory('Layout', function ($http, Notification, AnalysisConfig) {
     layoutPrototype.performLayout = function (net, options, defered) {

     if (net) {
        var address = AnalysisConfig.serverAddress + AnalysisConfig.resourceURI + AnalysisConfig.resources.blindLayout;
        $http.post(address, JSON.stringify(net), {timeout: AnalysisConfig.timeout})
        .then(function (response) {
            var data = response;
        },
        function (response) {
            Notification.error({
                title: 'Communication error',
                    ...
                });
            });
    }; 
};
```

My problem is that I can´t get data from the response. No matter what I tried, the result is always `undefined` or `[object Object]`. So how should I get data from response so I can for example use `alert()` and write something like

```
id01 (value of x, value of y)
id02 (value of x, value of y)
...
```

so I can also use it in my app?

Comment: if you use `then` then the json you looking for is in `response.data`

Comment: and how can I get for example x value of the second object (id02)?

Comment: if your result is `[object Object]` then parse to the json @Sefinek

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya if the result is [object Object] then it's already parsed!
@Sefinek, `response.data` will hold your JSON object, so you can access the values as `response.data.id01` and `response.data.id02`

Comment: @maurycy, Great, thank you. And can I also iterate over all objects?
Also if you put these things together in an answer I can accept it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `$http` returns a promise that's resolved with an object that contains more than just the body but also headers and status. So to retrieve the JSON you created on a backend you can do:

```
$http.post(address, JSON.stringify(net), {timeout: AnalysisConfig.timeout})
    .then(function (response) {
        var data = response.data;
    },
```

and then if you want to iterate over object keys you can do few things

```
for(var id in data){
  console.log(data[id]) //{"position":{"x":220,"y":90}}
  console.log(data[id].position) //{"x":220,"y":90}
}
```

or

```
var arrayOfObjects = Object.keys(data).map(function(id){
    return data[id].position;
});
console.log(arrayOfObjects) // [{"x":220,"y":90}, {"x":210,"y":250}]
```